# Creating class diagram for iPhone app

Tags: ios, class-diagram

Is it possible to generate a class diagram for an iPhone application? I want to see the flow of the code in a huge application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) will produce one for you! Be sure to read the manual for all the options.

Answer (score 1):

One of my friends suggested that I select the project file within XCode (at the very top of the Groups and Files pane), and go to `Design->Class Model->Quick Model`. But the problem is I am using latest version of xcode and I don't have design menu in my files pane.